# why is the key not added to the data in firebase?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've been struggling with the problem for a long time and I can't solve it.I'm in EditActivity trying to add a key to the data from the firebase that I get from it with the help of Ad and process it using the AdsManager.

The key should not be equal to zero. In this line I check if the key is zero, then the Firebase writes data to `empty.db.child (ad.key?: "Empty"). SetValue (ad)`. When I load the data to the Firebase, it shows them empty. Without displaying the key. You know what the problem is?

Ad

```
data class Ad(
    var user_id : String? = null ,
    var name : String? = null ,
    var button1 : String? = null ,
    val textTex : String? = null ,
    val textk : String? = null ,
    val description : String? = null,
    val name_ads: String?=null,
    val key :String? =null

)
```

AdsManager

```
class AdsManager(val readDataColbak : ReadDataColbak?) {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    val db =Firebase.database.getReference("main")
    fun pubilshAd(ad :Ad) {
       db.child(ad.key?: "empty").setValue(ad)

    }
    fun ReadDataDb() {
        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot : DataSnapshot) {
                val adArray =ArrayList<Ad>()
                for (item in snapshot.children){
                    val ad =item.children.iterator().next().child("ad").getValue(Ad::class.java)
                    adArray.add(ad !!)

                }
                readDataColbak?.readData(adArray)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error : DatabaseError) {
            }
        })

    }



}
```

EditActivity1

```
  class EditActivity1: AppCompatActivity(), FfragmentInterfes{
        lateinit var mBinder : ActivityEdit1Binding
      
        private var dialog=D()

        private var chooseImageFrog:FragmentList? =null
        val adsManager = AdsManager(null)
        public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            imageAdapter = ImageAdapter()
            mBinder=ActivityEdit1Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(mBinder.root)
            init()

        }
   fun onClickPublish(view : View) {
           adsManager.pubilshAd(fillAd())

        }
        private fun fillAd() : Ad {
            var ad : Ad
            mBinder.apply {
              ad= Ad(
                  name_ads.text.toString(),
                  user_id.text.toString(),
                    name.text.toString(),
                    button1.text.toString(),
                    description.text.toString(),
                  textk.text.toString(),
                  adsManager.db.push().key
                  )


            }
            return ad
        }
```

Comment: "the firebase says that the key is zero" Can you show more clearly what the problem is? Is there an error message? If so, include the exact error message and stack trace in your question please.

Comment: Ok.Now I'll tell you in more detail

Comment: Enough specifics?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(ad)` operation to see if something is w wrong?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are talking about more specifically?